# How to download pdf file from url in node.js?

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I am creating an application to download pdf files from url and show in my dashboard page as grid wise.

I am using node.js with express framework.

```
exports.pdf = function(req, response) {
    var url ="http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecopyrightform.pdf";

    http.get(url, function(res) {
     var chunks = [];
     res.on('data', function(chunk) {
     console.log('start');
     chunks.push(chunk);
    });

    res.on("end", function() {
      console.log('downloaded');
      var jsfile = new Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('base64');
      console.log('converted to base64');
      response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
      response.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');
     response.send(jsfile);
    });
    }).on("error", function() {
   console.log("error");
   }); 
};
```

Comment: post the code you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will Help.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/pdf");
```

[This Link will help](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#response.writeHead)

Answer (score 17):

For those looking to download a PDF server side, which is a bit of a different use case than the OP, here's how I did it using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) npm module:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const request = require("request-promise-native");

async function downloadPDF(pdfURL, outputFilename) {
    let pdfBuffer = await request.get({uri: pdfURL, encoding: null});
    console.log("Writing downloaded PDF file to " + outputFilename + "...");
    fs.writeFileSync(outputFilename, pdfBuffer);
}

downloadPDF("https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/ecf_faq.pdf", "c:/temp/somePDF.pdf");
```

Comment: this is not working it is giving me plain text file with pdf extension but not opening

Comment: @James It's not supposed to open. It's just supposed to save the file as c:\temp\somePDF.pdf. If you want it to open in your PDF viewer, that's a different question entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution I used to download pdf in node js is by **npm i node-downloader-helper** and just add downlaod url:

```
const { DownloaderHelper } = require('node-downloader-helper');

const download = new DownloaderHelper('url', __dirname);
download.on('end', () => console.log('Download Completed'))
download.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having issues (like I was) actually getting the PDF to open in a PDF viewer when using the request module, try setting the encoding in your call to null.
Something like this:

```
async function downloadPDF(pdfURL, outputFilename, token) {
  const options = {
    url: pdfURL,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token,
    },
    encoding: null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of node 18, you can do this with no third party dependencies, using the [native fetch API](https://dev.to/andrewbaisden/the-nodejs-18-fetch-api-72m) and the [native filesystem API](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/fs.html):

```
const pdfRespone = await fetch("https://example.com/file.pdf");
const pdfBuffer = await pdfRespone.arrayBuffer();
const binaryPdf = Buffer.from(pdfBuffer);
fs.writeFileSync("/your/file/name.pdf", binaryPdf, 'binary');
```

If you're dealing with very large files or have limited memory, [you could also do this with streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51302466/1209832), which would allow you to avoid loading the whole file into memory at once.