# How can I download and save a file using the Fetch API? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I have the url to a possibly large (100+ Mb) file, how do I save it in a local directory using fetch?

I looked around but there don't seem to be a lot of resources/tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: Node.js doesn't have Fetch integrated.

Comment: Why fetch? Node has http support?

Comment: I'm creating an Electron app, fetch is supported. Why fetch instead of pure http, because it's a lot easier to use (or so it seemed so far).

Comment: If someone looked for a way to save file using fetch api but in browser (and came across this answer) then please take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42274086/350384

Comment: See below for an example that uses the native Node.js http / https libraries. Note that I don't have to deal with 301/302, so it is straightforward.

Comment: @BenFortune it does as of 18+

Answer (score 125):

**Updated solution on Node 18:**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const { mkdir } = require("fs/promises");
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { finished } = require('stream/promises');
const path = require("path");
const downloadFile = (async (url, fileName) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  if (!fs.existsSync("downloads")) await mkdir("downloads"); //Optional if you already have downloads directory
  const destination = path.resolve("./downloads", fileName);
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(destination, { flags: 'wx' });
  await finished(Readable.fromWeb(res.body).pipe(fileStream));
});

await downloadFile("<url_to_fetch>", "<fileName>")
```

**Old Answer works till Node 16:**

Using the Fetch API you could write a function that could download from a URL like this:

You will need `node-fetch@2` run `npm i node-fetch@2`

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const fs = require("fs");
const downloadFile = (async (url, path) => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      res.body.pipe(fileStream);
      res.body.on("error", reject);
      fileStream.on("finish", resolve);
    });
});
```

Comment: You could even make it a little shorter by writing `res.body.on('error', reject);` and `fileStream.on('finish', resolve);`.

Comment: This gives an error: res.body.pipe is not a function. NodeJS v18

Comment: The function which calls downloadFile does not wait for it to resolve the promise. I'm calling this function like this-> await downloadFile(URL, path). Would you mind correcting me?

Comment: @tinkerr try importing and using 'node-fetch' instead of the normal fetch

Comment: just style preferences but especially for short example code I much prefer the explicit `async function downloadFile` style over `const somevar = `

Comment: Shouldn't an `async` function always return a `Promise`, rather than `await`ing one?

Comment: @serverpunk `downloadFile` will still return an empty promise because of the `async` keyword, but it won't return until awaiting the inner anonymous promise

Comment: @sloreti This might be a minor detail but it seems like `downloadFile` should return the `new Promise` and the outer code should call `await downloadFile()`, if I'm understanding the expected behavior of `async` functions correctly.

Comment: @serverpunk That entirely depends on what one wants the behavior of `downloadFile` to be! What I think you're describing would be effectively the same as the current answer

Comment: @Purefan https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding

Comment: @AhmedFasih I thought that was implied by me saying "just style preferences" but Im happy that you were able to still identify what I meant, good for you! :)

Comment: This does not work on node v18. I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/74722818 is a better solution in 2023.

Comment: Node 16 answer works on Node 18, Node 18 answer leads to 0 byte file.

Comment: It should be noted that `fromWeb` is flagged as experimental

Answer (score 40):

Older answers here involve `node-fetch`, but since `Node.js v18.x` this can be done with no extra dependencies.

The body of a fetch response is a [web stream](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/). It can be converted to a Node `fs` stream using [`Readable.fromWeb`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamreadablefromwebreadablestream-options), which can then be piped into a write stream created by `fs.createWriteStream`. If desired, the resulting stream can then be turned into a `Promise` using the promise version of [`stream.finished`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streamfinishedstream-options-callback).

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { finished } = require('stream/promises');

const stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt');
const { body } = await fetch('https://example.com');
await finished(Readable.fromWeb(body).pipe(stream));
```

Comment: That can also be nicely compacted in one line `const download = async (url, path) => Readable.fromWeb((await fetch(url)).body).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))`

Comment: Does this download the entire file (`await fetch(...)`) before starting the write stream?

Comment: @1252748 `await fetch(...)` finishes after the response headers are fully received, but before the response body is received. The body will be streamed into the file while it is arriving. The second `await` can be omitted to perform other tasks while the body stream is still in progress.

Comment: `Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadableStream<any>'.
  Type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReadableStream<any>': values, [Symbol.asyncIterator]ts(2345)`

Comment: @RonH unfortunately it looks like there are 2 _different_ `ReadableStream` definitions, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63630114/argument-of-type-readablestreamany-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-r. You should be able to cast `body` to the correct `ReadableStream` from `'stream/web'`; i.e. `import { ReadableStream } from 'stream/web';` and `body as ReadableStream<any>`.

Comment: Ends in 0 byte file for me.

Comment: Could probably be rewrited with propre `import` as Node support it easily.

Answer (score 27):

If you want to avoid explicitly making a Promise like in the other very fine answer, and are ok with building a buffer of the entire 100+ MB file, then you could do something simpler:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {writeFile} = require('fs');
const {promisify} = require('util');
const writeFilePromise = promisify(writeFile);

function downloadFile(url, outputPath) {
  return fetch(url)
      .then(x => x.arrayBuffer())
      .then(x => writeFilePromise(outputPath, Buffer.from(x)));
}
```

But the other answer will be more memory-efficient since it's piping the received data stream directly into a file without accumulating all of it in a Buffer.

Comment: I have tried this code but got error...I got error [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open 'D:\Work\repo\'] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\Work\\repo\\'
}

Comment: @ScottJones `EISDIR` means "Error: IS Directory": you're giving Node a directory when it expects a file. Just use `d:\work\repo\file.txt` for example

Answer (score 11):

```js
const {createWriteStream} = require('fs');
const {pipeline} = require('stream/promises');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const downloadFile = async (url, path) => pipeline(
    (await fetch(url)).body,
    createWriteStream(path)
);
```

Comment: I get error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at destroyer (internal/streams/pipeline.js:23:10)`

Answer (score 6):

This is now easy using modern nodejs api. This will not read the file into memory so can be used with huge files and is great for performance.

```
import { writeFile } from 'node:fs/promises'
import { Readable } from 'node:stream'

const response = await fetch('https://example.com/pdf')
const body = Readable.fromWeb(response.body)
await writeFile('document.pdf', body)
```

Comment: I believe that that stores the intermediate result in memory which might be undesirable, especially for larger files.

Comment: Updated answer. It no longer loads file into memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
import { existsSync } from "fs";
import { mkdir, writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import { join } from "path";

export const download = async (url: string, ...folders: string[]) => {
    const fileName = url.split("/").pop();

    const path = join("./downloads", ...folders);

    if (!existsSync(path)) await mkdir(path);

    const filePath = join(path, fileName);

    const response = await fetch(url);

    const blob = await response.blob();

    // const bos = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer())
    const bos = blob.stream();

    await writeFile(filePath, bos);

    return { path, fileName, filePath };
};

// call like that ↓
await download("file-url", "subfolder-1", "subfolder-2", ...)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: this will store the whole 100MB file in memory before writing it, which might work but you probably want to avoid that if possible

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for kinda a same usage, wanted to fetch bunch of api endpoints and save the json responses to some static files, so I came up creating my own solution, hope it helps

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    VERSIOINS_FILE_PATH = './static/data/versions.json',
    endpoints = [
        {
            name: 'example1',
            type: 'exampleType1',
            url: 'https://example.com/api/url/1',
            filePath: './static/data/exampleResult1.json',
            updateFrequency: 7 // days
        },
        {
            name: 'example2',
            type: 'exampleType1',
            url: 'https://example.com/api/url/2',
            filePath: './static/data/exampleResult2.json',
            updateFrequency: 7
        },
        {
            name: 'example3',
            type: 'exampleType2',
            url: 'https://example.com/api/url/3',
            filePath: './static/data/exampleResult3.json',
            updateFrequency: 30
        },
        {
            name: 'example4',
            type: 'exampleType2',
            url: 'https://example.com/api/url/4',
            filePath: './static/data/exampleResult4.json',
            updateFrequency: 30
        },
    ],
    checkOrCreateFolder = () => {
        var dir = './static/data/';
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
    },
    syncStaticData = () => {
        checkOrCreateFolder();
        let fetchList = [],
            versions = [];
        endpoints.forEach(endpoint => {
            if (requiresUpdate(endpoint)) {
                console.log(`Updating ${endpoint.name} data... : `, endpoint.filePath);
                fetchList.push(endpoint)
            } else {
                console.log(`Using cached ${endpoint.name} data... : `, endpoint.filePath);
                let endpointVersion = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(endpoint.filePath, 'utf8')).lastUpdate;
                versions.push({
                    name: endpoint.name + "Data",
                    version: endpointVersion
                });
            }
        })
        if (fetchList.length > 0) {
            Promise.all(fetchList.map(endpoint => fetch(endpoint.url, { "method": "GET" })))
                .then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(response => response.json())))
                .then(results => {
                    results.forEach((endpointData, index) => {
                        let endpoint = fetchList[index]
                        let processedData = processData(endpoint.type, endpointData.data)
                        let fileData = {
                            data: processedData,
                            lastUpdate: Date.now() // unix timestamp
                        }
                        versions.push({
                            name: endpoint.name + "Data",
                            version: fileData.lastUpdate
                        })
                        fs.writeFileSync(endpoint.filePath, JSON.stringify(fileData));
                        console.log('updated data: ', endpoint.filePath);
                    })
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        fs.writeFileSync(VERSIOINS_FILE_PATH, JSON.stringify(versions));
        console.log('updated versions: ', VERSIOINS_FILE_PATH);
    },
    recursiveRemoveKey = (object, keyname) => {
        object.forEach((item) => {
            if (item.items) { //items is the nesting key, if it exists, recurse , change as required
                recursiveRemoveKey(item.items, keyname)
            }
            delete item[keyname];
        })
    },
    processData = (type, data) => {
        //any thing you want to do with the data before it is written to the file
        let processedData = type === 'vehicle' ? processType1Data(data) : processType2Data(data);
        return processedData;
    },
    processType1Data = data => {
        let fetchedData = [...data]
        recursiveRemoveKey(fetchedData, 'count')
        return fetchedData
    },
    processType2Data = data => {
        let fetchedData = [...data]
        recursiveRemoveKey(fetchedData, 'keywords')
        return fetchedData
    },
    requiresUpdate = endpoint => {
        if (fs.existsSync(endpoint.filePath)) {
            let fileData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(endpoint.filePath));
            let lastUpdate = fileData.lastUpdate;
            let now = new Date();
            let diff = now - lastUpdate;
            let diffDays = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            if (diffDays >= endpoint.updateFrequency) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true
    };

syncStaticData();
```

[link to github gist](https://gist.github.com/mhshakouri/fdf7fdebbf3288e67152322153f31d76)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to deal with 301/302 responses (when things have been moved), you can actually just do it in one line with the Node.js native libraries `http` and/or `https`.

You can run this example oneliner in the `node` shell. It just uses `https` module to download a GNU zip file of some source code to the directory where you started the `node` shell. (You start a `node` shell by typing `node` at the command line for your OS where Node.js has been installed).

`require('https').get("https://codeload.github.com/angstyloop/js-utils/tar.gz/refs/heads/develop", it => it.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream("develop.tar.gz")));`

If you don't need/want HTTPS use this instead:

`require('http').get("http://codeload.github.com/angstyloop/js-utils/tar.gz/refs/heads/develop", it => it.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream("develop.tar.gz")));`

Answer (score 0):

This got the job done for me node 18 and presumably 16. Has only fs and node-fetch (probably works with other fetch libraries) as a dependency.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
async function downloadImage(imageUrl){
    //imageurl https://example.com/uploads/image.jpg
    imageUrl = imageUrl.split('/').slice(-1) //image.jpg
    const res = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(`./folder/${imageUrl}`);
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.body.pipe(fileStream);
        res.body.on("error", reject);
        fileStream.on("finish", resolve);
      });
  };
```

Previous top answer by @code_wrangler was split into a node 16 and 18 solution (this is like the 16 solution), but on Node 18 the Node 18 solution created a 0 byte file for me and cost me some time.