# Unable to download a file using fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Trying to download a file in nodejs server:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Readable } = require('stream');
const { finished } = require('stream/promises');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const url = 'https://dl.mahtabmusic.ir/1394/2/s-music/Dariush%20-%20Parastesh.mp3'
const stream = fs.createWriteStream(`${directory}/${name}`);
const response = await fetch(url);
await finished(Readable.fromWeb(response.body).pipe(stream));
```

And I get this error:

> https://dl.mahtabmusic.ir/1394/2/s-music/Dariush%20-%20Parastesh.mp3
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "readableStream" argument must
> be an instance of ReadableStream. Received an instance of PassThrough

Any solutions?

Comment: I don't know what version of node you are using, but N.B. node has had an experimental implementation of the fetch API natively for a few versions and it hit stable in 21. You may not need node-fetch.

Comment: Does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614649/how-can-i-download-and-save-a-file-using-the-fetch-api-node-js